# Import camera parameters and data from *.sif image files?

Tags: import, code-request

By default, [Andor](http://www.andor.com/)'s line of scientific cameras saves data in an apparently undocumented *.sif format. Are there any *Mathematica* packages or code that can help import these data?

I've inherited an archive of experimental data stored in this format, and I'd like to seamlessly process it in *Mathematica*.

It seems that someone has managed to reverse engineer a limited portion of the format for Matlab ([sifread.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11224-andor-sif-image-reader)), and there is also an ImageJ plugin for reading .sif images ([OpenSIF_.java](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/download/OpenSIF_.java)), but so far I haven't gotten these working with *Mathematica*.

Comment: I just updated my version of SOLIS lately and I noticed that there is now a SIF file library included with it. I don't think SIF files really have any advantage over FITS, but if you need to read them, you could write a LibraryLink interface to this library.

Answer (score 7):

As a workaround, you can use the batch converter included with the Andor SOLIS software to convert SIF files to [FITS format](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/FITS.html). FITS is not only very similar to SIF (to the best of my knowledge), but also can be loaded into Mathematica without any problem. You will notice that the file sizes are virtually the same for both formats.

When I visited Andor's factory a few years ago, I commented to one of their engineers that I used the FITS format for interoperability with other software, but that it is a nuisance to have to save the SIF and the FITS files separately. He suggested to me to use FITS by default rather than SIF, as he does: it not only contains all necessary metadata and can be loaded and saved by SOLIS just as easily as SIF files can, but it is also readable by other software.